# Observe/capture 302 redirects in java

Tags: java, http, redirect, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-302

I have a web application under test. Using Fiddler/Httpfox, I can see that on logging in to the web app, there are TWO 302 HTTP redirects before a 200 OK is response is received. Is it possible to observe the two redirects using Java code?

This is what I coded:

```
public class HttpReq {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    URL address = null;
    String line = null;

    HttpReq () {
      try {
        address = new URL("http://walhs24002v.us.oracle.com/t1mockapp1/");
        con = (HttpURLConnection)address.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setReadTimeout(60000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        con.connect();

        InputStreamReader is  = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
        br = new BufferedReader(is);
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            str.append(line + '\n');
        }
        //System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
      }
      catch (MalformedURLException m)
      {
        m.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (IOException i)
      {
        i.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
        br = null;
        str = null;
        con = null;
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpReq http = new HttpReq();
      }

}
```

The program gives the output:
200 
OK

No surprises there. Is there a way to capture the two 302 redirects before the 200 ok is received?

Comment: setInstanceFollowRedirects(false) ?

Comment: @irreputable: Yup that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With defaulthttpclient you most certainly can:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html

> ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS='http.protocol.handle-redirects': 
>   defines whether redirects should be handled automatically. This
>   parameter expects a value of type java.lang.Boolean. If this parameter
>   is not set HttpClient will handle redirects automatically.